# Javascript decode hex string with backslash

Tags: javascript, utf-8, hex

I got the hex string from sever:

```
const res = {"data": "\\xf0\\x9d\\x90\\x81"};
```

The original text is:

> 

I'm used decodeURIComponent and escape function got:

```
decodeURIComponent(escape(res.data));
// "\xf0\x9d\x90\x81"
```

How to decode hex string with double backslash?

Comment: `decodeURIComponent(res.data.replace(/\\x/g, '%'))`

Answer (score 0):

Just a little sample for u.
Hope it works!!

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <body>



    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {

     var uri_enc = '\\xf0\\x9d\\x90\\x81';


     var uri_dec= decodeURIComponent(uri_enc.replace(/\\x/g, '%'));
      var res = "Encoded URI: " + uri_enc + "<br>" + "Decoded URI: " + uri_dec;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
     }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Result will be like this:

```
    Encoded URI: \xf0\x9d\x90\x81
    Decoded URI:
```

If not working tell us, we will share more solutions!!